# Floated Div is going out and under the Outline-container

Tags: html, css, css-float, containers

I have a question regarding divs and floats. I have searched a lot but can't seem to find anything that will fix my problem/work.

I am making a website and have two in-line divs: a description and a hours box. They are both set under a slideshow div and all three are set inside an outline/container. I'm trying to make it work for multiple window sizes, but whenever the outline div hits the bottom of either the hour or the description divs, they seem to float outside.

I'm kind of bad at explaining things so you can just look at bit of code:

```
div#outline{
clear: both;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
border: 5px solid white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px #000000;
}

div#slideshow{
width: 50%;
min-width:700px;
height: 530px;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top: 30px;
}

#description{
width: 600px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
}

#hours{
position: relative;
border: 5px solid green;
background-image: url("#");
height: 270px;
width: 220px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px #000000;
float: left;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The full thing can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/wfq0kg0L/

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand the problem but I think it may come from using`height: 100%;` from the html tag down. I dont recommend doing this at all. It can be very annoying. Be responsive only using width or using media queries to set a proper height.

Also you should use `overflow:hidden;`on the outline div to not showing content outside of its boundaries.

Comment: I'm using height: 100%; in the outline because I want it to stretch the whole page. The problem is that the description and hours divs are not supposed to extend outside of the outline div, but they do when the window is resized. And when overflow:hidden; is used, the outline div cuts off the description and hours divs at smaller window sizes.

Comment: Yes, but using always height:100% is the same as not using it, in fact, you cant take all the percentages heights and you will get the same result page. What gives the outline div its height is the sum of the absolute heights of its child divs, in this case only the slideshow div. What you can do is to put the description and hours divs inside of a new div and give that div a relative position and a px height. If you want to change the properties depending on the windows size you need to use media queries, a framework like bootstrap makes that really easy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding your problem..Looks like everything is working fine to me..All I can guess is that you want the `div#outline` to *not* float outside of one of your div containers? I don't see it floating outside.

Here's a quick recommendation tho..You don't need to be calling `div#outline` just `#outline` will do just fine. Also why are you using all `div` id's? You can each `div` a class. IE..

**HTML**

```
<div class="outline">
   <div class="slideshow"></div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slideshow{} 
.outline{}
```

This will clean up your css.

Also Look into [flex-box](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). It's much easier to do layout this way now and it's widely supported across browsers. No need to float anymore.

Why are't you using a simple grid framework that will def help you with this kind of thing.

I have a repo on github that you can learn about [flex-box](https://github.com/kapena/FlexyBoxes) at.

Check it out. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove height:100% from .outline or make it min-height:100% instead of height:100%
2. After div id="hours" add